# Should "Me'en Sheva" (Magen Avot) be recited at a hotel on Friday night?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, travel, maariv, leil-shabbat

The prayer "Me'en Sheva" or "Magen Avot" which is recited in shul in Friday nights after the silent Shemoneh Esreh was instituted to accommodate late-comers so that people would walk home from shul together to avoid dangers.

Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 268:10 says:

> אין אומרים ברכה מעין שבע בבית חתנים ואבלים דליכא טעמא דמאחרין לבוא
>   שיהיו ניזוקין:

In brief, in a house that has a groom or mourner, this prayer is not said, because there is no concern of late-comers.

Some commentators have explained this concept that a non permanent "place" that does not have a regular minyan doesn't require saying this prayer.

In a few months, my friend's son will have his aufruf in a hotel. This hotel occasionally has Jewish groups and they set up a room for a minyan, when needed. However, it is a hotel - not a shul. But it is also not someone's home - it's a public place. It's not exactly as the Shulchan Aruch describes.

Does the Shulchan Aruch's principle apply to davening in a hotel Friday night?

Comment: "a house that has a groom or mourner": I think this should be "a groom's or mourner's house".

Comment: The second-last paragraph sounds like a Rfפ.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [discussion regarding this here](http://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=440&article=1652).

In conclusion a case could be made for both saying or omitting "Me'en Sheva" thus creating a situation of Safek.  The author of the above article concludes:

> the Pri Megadim (MZ 268:8) raises the possibility that those who
>   recite Me'en Sheva out of doubt run the risk of a beracha l’vatala (in vain).
>   Thus, in the final analysis, it is safer to rule that one should not
>   have recited MS, but if they did (which I guess most groups do) there
>   was insufficient reason to try to dissuade them.

As always - for practical halacha always consult with your Rav :)

Answer (score 0):

> In a few months, my friend's son will have his aufruf in a hotel. This hotel occasionally has Jewish groups and they set up a room for a minyan, when needed. However, it is a hotel - not a shul. But it is also not someone's home - it's a public place. It's not exactly as the Shulchan Aruch describes.

I have often stayed at a hotel like this for Shabbatonim.

The custom there is to recite it.

Comment: Actually, my friend and his father are both rabbanim, and they had an interesting email debate on this question. There are valid rules to go either way. When I can, I'll try to paste and condense parts of their discussion.

Comment: The custom _where_? And did they do so with any Rabbinic sanction?